VBA to Filter data from table and pick random samples from it based on multiple Conditions and paste the data in a new Sheet
I need some help with my excel macro. The following is the background of the VBA:

I have a table in the first sheet of my Excel named "RawSheet1". The table has 18 columns of data from the audit of 2 to 3 associates. The table may sometimes have the data of only 1 associate/multiple associates; hence, the rows in the table are always dynamic.

The macro runs mainly based on 2 columns in the table - Column E (5th Column) and Column K (11th Column). "Column E" has the associate ID and "Column K" has the source detail.

First step is that the Macro should rename the header of "Column E" to "Examiner". Then it should filter Column E for the samples of 1 associate.

Second: the macro should Filter "Column K" which has the header "Source". This Column (Column K) will usually have a mix of these sources - Compatible, Incompatible, Wrong Detail, Duplicate, Missing.<br />Additionally, the Compatible source usually has a few variations in the table as well, for example: Compatible - OS, Compatible - UPC, Compatible - Active, etc.

Third step(main step): The macro should generate 10 random samples (10 rows) from the data available after applying the above two filters. The number of samples (10) is absolute number. If the data obtained is less than 10, it should consider all the data available.
If the data obtained after the filter is more than 10 rows, then it should generate samples based on the below conditions:

1st Condition: If Column K has only "Compatible" and "Incompatible" sources in it, then the samples drawn will be 40% Incompatible(4) and 60% Compatible(6). If the "Incompatible" samples obtained is only 3(30%), 2(20%) or 1(10%), then rest of the random samples are drawn from "Compatible" data.
2nd Condition: If Column K has multiple sources, for Example: 10 Compatible, 8 Incompatible, 3 Duplicate and 5 Wrong Data - the macro should pick 60% Compatible(6), 30% Incompatible(3) and 10% Wrong(1) samples. Here preference for the 10% is first given to "Wrong", then "Duplicate" and finally to "Missing".<br />Furthermore, if the "Incompatible" samples obtained is only 2 (20%) or 1 (10%), then rest of the random samples are drawn from "Compatible" data.


Forth Step: Create a new Sheet called "TempData" and copy all the headers from the table in Sheet "RawSheet1" to the Sheet "TempData".

Fifth Step: The random samples finally obtained are copied without the headers to the Sheet "TempData".

Sixth Step: Repeat all the steps for the 2nd Associate ID and paste the samples in the Sheet "TempData" after the first associates samples.

Seventh Step(last step): Copy Columns A, C, E, H, I, K and L from the sheet "TempData" and paste them in a new sheet called "OutputData". The columns should be pasted in the following order: Column A first, followed by Column E, Column C, Column H, I, and K last.

Finally it should give a popup Message box "Samples Generated Successfully".
The following is my code so far:


Sub GenerateRandomSamples()
    Dim wsRaw As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngFiltered As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, sampleCount As Long, rowCount As Long
    Dim examinerID As Variant, sources As Range
    Dim tempRow As Long, outputRow As Long
    Dim sourceDict As Object, i As Long
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    Dim assocID As Range, kCol As Range
    Dim sampleLimit As Long: sampleLimit = 10
    
    ' Set up worksheets
    Set wsRaw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CollatedData")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempData")
    If wsTemp Is Nothing Then
        Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=wsRaw)
        wsTemp.Name = "TempData"
    Else
        wsTemp.Cells.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Copy headers from CollatedData to TempData
    wsRaw.Rows(1).Copy wsTemp.Rows(1)
    tempRow = 2 ' Start copying data from second row
    
    ' Rename column E header to "Examiner"
    wsRaw.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Examiner"
    
    ' Filter by each unique Examiner ID (associate) in Column E
    Set rng = wsRaw.Range("E2:E" & wsRaw.Cells(wsRaw.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each assocID In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        examinerID = assocID.Value
        
        ' Apply filters to columns E (Examiner) and K (Source)
        wsRaw.AutoFilterMode = False
        wsRaw.Range("A1:R" & wsRaw.Cells(wsRaw.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=examinerID
        
        ' Capture filtered rows for further processing
        Set rngFiltered = wsRaw.Range("A1:R" & wsRaw.Cells(wsRaw.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rowCount = rngFiltered.Rows.Count - 1 ' Exclude header row
        
        ' Initialize dictionary to track sample proportions
        Set sourceDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set kCol = wsRaw.Range("K2:K" & wsRaw.Cells(wsRaw.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        ' Loop through Column K and count each source type based on partial match for "Compatible"
        For Each cell In kCol
            If cell.Value Like "Compatible*" Then
                ' Handle all variations of "Compatible"
                If Not sourceDict.exists("Compatible") Then
                    sourceDict.Add "Compatible", 0
                End If
                sourceDict("Compatible") = sourceDict("Compatible") + 1
            ElseIf cell.Value = "Incompatible" Then
                ' Exact match for "Incompatible"
                If Not sourceDict.exists("Incompatible") Then
                    sourceDict.Add "Incompatible", 0
                End If
                sourceDict("Incompatible") = sourceDict("Incompatible") + 1
            ElseIf cell.Value = "Wrong Detail" Then
                ' Exact match for "Wrong Detail"
                If Not sourceDict.exists("Wrong Detail") Then
                    sourceDict.Add "Wrong Detail", 0
                End If
                sourceDict("Wrong Detail") = sourceDict("Wrong Detail") + 1
            ElseIf cell.Value = "Duplicate" Then
                ' Exact match for "Duplicate"
                If Not sourceDict.exists("Duplicate") Then
                    sourceDict.Add "Duplicate", 0
                End If
                sourceDict("Duplicate") = sourceDict("Duplicate") + 1
            ElseIf cell.Value = "Missing" Then
                ' Exact match for "Missing"
                If Not sourceDict.exists("Missing") Then
                    sourceDict.Add "Missing", 0
                End If
                sourceDict("Missing") = sourceDict("Missing") + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        
        ' Determine sample sizes based on conditions (Compatible/Incompatible, multiple sources)
        Dim compatibleSamples As Long, incompatibleSamples As Long, wrongSamples As Long
        compatibleSamples = 0: incompatibleSamples = 0: wrongSamples = 0
        Dim totalRows As Long
        totalRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(kCol)
        
        If sourceDict.exists("Compatible") And sourceDict.exists("Incompatible") Then
            ' Only Compatible and Incompatible
            incompatibleSamples = Application.Min(sourceDict("Incompatible"), sampleLimit * 0.4)
            compatibleSamples = sampleLimit - incompatibleSamples
        Else
            ' Multiple sources case
            compatibleSamples = Application.Min(sourceDict("Compatible"), sampleLimit * 0.6)
            incompatibleSamples = Application.Min(sourceDict("Incompatible"), sampleLimit * 0.3)
            wrongSamples = Application.Min(sourceDict("Wrong Detail"), sampleLimit * 0.1)
            If wrongSamples < sampleLimit * 0.1 Then
                wrongSamples = wrongSamples + Application.Min(sourceDict("Duplicate"), sampleLimit * 0.1 - wrongSamples)
            End If
        End If
        
        ' Ensure we have enough samples
        If rowCount < sampleLimit Then
            rngFiltered.Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=wsTemp.Cells(tempRow, 1)
            tempRow = tempRow + rowCount
        Else
            ' Random sampling
            For i = 1 To sampleLimit
                ' Code to copy random sample rows based on calculated proportions
                ' You can implement random sampling logic here
            Next i
        End If
        
        wsRaw.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next assocID
    
    ' Copy relevant columns to Output_samples
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output_samples")
    If wsOutput Is Nothing Then
        Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=wsTemp)
        wsOutput.Name = "Output_samples"
    Else
        wsOutput.Cells.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Copy A, C, E, H, I, K from TempData to Output_samples
    wsTemp.Range("A:A,C:C,E:E,H:H,I:I,K:K").Copy wsOutput.Cells(1, 1)
    
    ' Final message
    MsgBox "Samples Generated Successfully", vbInformation
End Sub

Issues with the code:

If my source table has data of only 1 associate, the code doesn't pick any samples at all. IT just copies the headers to Temp Sheet and the output is also a blank sheet with Headers only.

When my table has data of 2 associates - this code does create a filter for one associate at a time, but it doesn't pick exactly ten samples. It just picks excess data from only 1 associate.


Furthermore, if the sample sizes in my source table for 1 associate are less than or equal to 10, the macro does not have to pick any percentage but should paste the full sample size in the output sheet and then move on to the next associate, if any. This is not happening when using this macro as well.
When I tested this macro to pull data from a table with info of 2 associates (1 associate had 9 source samples and 2nd had 21 rows of data) - it picked 20 samples from the 2nd associate alone.
I'm not sure what's wrong with the code. Could someone help me out with this? Thank you in advance.
